# Xamarin Studio 5.1 Build Error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying Xamarin Studio 5.1 (build 479)
Building the example Apps (Xamarin Store or Employee Directory) I get:
"Error: Build failed. See the build log for details."
I have uninstalled and re installed the IDE with same results!
And I can't start evaluating the product.

Following are some errors from the log directory

The first Error in log file "Ide.2014-07-02__15-43-46" is:

```
ERROR [2014-07-02 15:44:38Z]: Could not update jumplists
System.InvalidOperationException: The file type is not registered with this application.
   ב-  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.AppendCustomCategories()
   ב-  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.Refresh()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.UpdateJumpList()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.Run()
```

and then

```
INFO [2014-07-02 15:50:45Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.ILAsmBinding
INFO [2014-07-02 15:50:45Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Deployment.Linux
INFO [2014-07-02 15:50:46Z]: ANDROID: Starting Android device monitor
INFO [2014-07-02 15:50:46Z]: ANDROID: Adb server launch operation completed
INFO [2014-07-02 15:50:46Z]: ANDROID: Creating android device tracker
INFO [2014-07-02 15:50:46Z]: ANDROID: Got new device list from adb
ERROR [2014-07-02 15:50:50Z]: Could not update jumplists
System.InvalidOperationException: The file type is not registered with this application.
   ב-  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.AppendCustomCategories()
   ב-  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.Refresh()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.UpdateJumpList()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.OnUpdateTimerEllapsed(Object sender, EventArgs args)
INFO [2014-07-02 15:50:52Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.HexEditor
WARNING [2014-07-02 15:50:52Z]: GLib-GObject-Warning: Attempt to add property __gtksharp_73_Mono_TextEditor_TextArea::im-module after class was initialised
Stack trace: 
   ב-  GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_property(IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr nick, IntPtr blurb, UInt32 property_id, IntPtr property_type, Boolean can_read, Boolean can_write)
   ב-  GLib.Object.AddProperties(GType gtype, Type t)
   ב-  GLib.Object.RegisterGType(Type t)
   ב-  GLib.Object.LookupGType(Type t)
   ב-  GLib.Object.LookupGType()
   ב-  GLib.Object.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)
   ב-  Gtk.Widget.CreateNativeObject(String[] names, Value[] vals)
   ב-  Gtk.Container..ctor()
   ב-  Mono.TextEditor.TextArea..ctor(TextDocument doc, ITextEditorOptions options, EditMode initialMode)
   ב-  Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor..ctor(TextDocument doc, ITextEditorOptions options, EditMode initialMode)
   ב-  Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor..ctor(TextDocument doc, ITextEditorOptions options)
   ב-  Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor..ctor(TextDocument doc)
   ב-  Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor..ctor()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.ExtensibleTextEditor..ctor(SourceEditorView view)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorWidget..ctor(SourceEditorView view)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView..ctor()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorDisplayBinding.CreateContent(FilePath fileName, String mimeType, Project ownerProject)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.LoadFileWrapper.Invoke(String fileName)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.RealOpenFile(IProgressMonitor monitor, FileOpenInformation openFileInfo)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.BatchOpenDocument(IProgressMonitor monitor, FilePath fileName, Project project, Int32 line, Int32 column)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.OnLoadingWorkspaceUserPreferences(Object s, UserPreferencesEventArgs args)
   ב-  System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.RootWorkspace.RestoreWorkspacePreferences(WorkspaceItem item)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.RootWorkspace.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<BackgroundLoadWorkspace>b__1a(Object param0, EventArgs param1)
   ב-  Gtk.Application.InvokeCB.Invoke()
   ב-  GLib.Timeout.TimeoutProxy.Handler()
   ב-  Gtk.Application.gtk_main()
   ב-  Gtk.Application.Run()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Run()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer)
   ב-  Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

ERROR [2014-07-02 15:50:57Z]: Could not update jumplists
System.InvalidOperationException: The file type is not registered with this application.
   ב-  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.AppendCustomCategories()
   ב-  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.Refresh()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.UpdateJumpList()
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.OnUpdateTimerEllapsed(Object sender, EventArgs args)
ERROR [2014-07-02 15:53:59Z]: System.ArgumentException: minimumEdition
   ב-  Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationReason..ctor(XamarinProduct product, Restriction restriction, XamarinEdition minimumEdition, String errorText, String errorCode, String restrictedItem)
   ב-  Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationReason.FromToolError(String errorCode, String errorText)
   ב-  Xamarin.Ide.ActivationHelper.<HandleToolErrors>b__3(BuildError be)
   ב-  System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   ב-  System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   ב-  System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   ב-  System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   ב-  Xamarin.Ide.ActivationHelper.HandleToolErrors(BuildResult br, Boolean rebuild)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.MonoDroidBuildExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, SolutionEntityItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, SolutionEntityItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, SolutionEntityItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, SolutionEntityItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.CustomCommandExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, SolutionEntityItem entry, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, ConfigurationSelector solutionConfiguration, Boolean buildReferences)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionFolder.OnBuild(IProgressMonitor monitor, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionFolder.OnRunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.DefaultProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, ConfigurationSelector solutionConfiguration, Boolean buildReferences)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.Solution.OnBuild(IProgressMonitor monitor, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.WorkspaceItem.OnRunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.DefaultProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, Solution solution, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, WorkspaceItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, Solution solution, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, WorkspaceItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, Solution solution, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, WorkspaceItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, Solution solution, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, WorkspaceItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, Solution solution, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, WorkspaceItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, Solution solution, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, WorkspaceItem item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.Build(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, IBuildTarget item, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Projects.WorkspaceItem.RunTarget(IProgressMonitor monitor, String target, ConfigurationSelector configuration)
   ב-  MonoDevelop.Ide.ProjectOperations.BuildSolutionItemAsync(IBuildTarget entry, IProgressMonitor monitor, ITimeTracker tt)
INFO [2014-07-02 17:03:01Z]: ANDROID: Stopping Android device monitor
INFO [2014-07-02 17:04:33Z]: ANDROID: Starting Android device monitor
INFO [2014-07-02 17:04:33Z]: ANDROID: Adb server launch operation completed
INFO [2014-07-02 17:04:33Z]: ANDROID: Creating android device tracker
INFO [2014-07-02 17:04:33Z]: ANDROID: Got new device list from adb
```

and many more!!!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not use a sample app. Though convenient for reference, they can be difficult for learning (and troubleshooting) as there is a lot of code. Initially it might not be obvious as to where in the code to start. Instead, consider making an app incrementally following one of the guides, such as the [the iOS hello guides](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/). That way, you can build the application incrementally. If you run into a problem, you can typically pin it down to your latest change.

If you want to stick with the sample apps, try:

1. In the past, [others have seen this issue in updates](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8949/can-t-view-axml-layout-renderer-failed) and have resolved by a slight downgrade. Try un-installing and installing 5.0.1 instead of 5.1. To install, the older version, navigate to [this Xamarin download page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads) and click *Show All Versions*.
2. Activate a free 30-day Business Edition license . This will give you access to Xamarin's customer support. They may have seen this issue. Here are [instructions for activating a trial](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/beginning_a_xamarin_trial/).